# Issue with nginx proxy_pass and couchdb

Tags: nginx, couchdb, proxypass

I wanted to serve couchdb on port 80 using nginx. I basically setup the nginx conf files like this:

```
upstream couchdb {
    server 127.0.0.1:5984;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log /path/to/log/couchdb.log;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        proxy_pass http://couchdb;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The configuration seems to work except for a particular case.
When I type `http://example.com/_utils/` I get to the couchdb instance, but if I type `http://example.com/_utils` (note missing trailing slash) I get nothing because I am being redirected to `http://couchdb/_utils`. Note that both `http://example.com:5984/_utils/` and `http://example.com:5984/_utils` work fine.

My WAG is that the issue is with the nginx configuration but I am not sure how that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the culprit is `proxy_redirect off;`. Why did you turn it off?

Comment: Thanks. That was something I thought was needed in order to allow for some CORS operations.